# алгоритм разбиения doxc на равные части java

Tags: java, html, парсер, docx

Мне нужно перевести docx файл(там есть таблицы, картинки и прочее) в html и отображать на странице. Нашел 3 более менее нормальные библиотеки: doc4j, jodconverter, apache poi. Конвертнуть просто весь файл в html я нашел как.

Моя проблема состоит в том, что я не могу придумать по какому критерию разделить файл. Может быть можно как то узнать высоту/ширину html части при конвертации. Или как-то при разделении эмулировать экран, и как выйдет текст за предел, взять эту часть. И есть проблема с таблицами, если они сильно большие, или вообще таблица в таблице. Делить на части docx, а потом переводить в html, или конвертировать весь docx а потом делить на части html код не имеет значение, все идеи приветствуются.

Все будет храниться в бд(и text и html), что бы данные грузить частями при прокрутке, а не сразу целиком. Часть примерно должна быть на размер экрана, может чуть чуть больше. Что бы проще было, допустим разрешение 1024 786.

Помогите нормальной идеей или как это можно сделать, у меня опыта и знаний для этого видимо еще не достаточно. А если будет еще и пример кода, будет вообще прекрасно. Если где-то непонятно написал или запутал, спрашивайте. Спасибо

Comment: Разбейте текст на смысловые части, абзацы, пожалуйста. Читать невозможно )

Comment: Сам документ же разделен на страницы. Вам этого не достаточно? Если нет, то видимо данные из файла будут представлены на сайте не как документ? Тогда руками разделяйте его, как ещё.

Comment: @iksuy Документ на страницы не разделен никак внутри. Что руками разделять это понятно. А по какому критерию? что бы каждая часть по высоте в браузере выглядела примерно одинаково?